# how would i implement the image processing technology within this iphone application?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, camera

Just a quick question on the iphone technology within this business card reader

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F8z6pcxdrPo

as we can see this video allows users to take a photo of a business card, i have an idea where i would take a photo of some text , and that photo could then be turned into text on the iphone. how would i be able to implement this using the iOS API ?

cheers guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera stuff is all standard-- use the [`UIImagePickerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) for this.

Text recognition (OCR) is not a built in part of the iOS API, though, so that part really isn't trivial. There are multiple open-source projects that can handle this sort of thing if you want to go after them.

[Tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is an older but possibly viable one. Check out [this post](http://robertcarlsen.net/2010/09/24/compiling-tesseract-v3-for-iphone-1299) which has info on cross compiling it for iOS.

Other users here might have more current recommendations.